# Knockout: How do I toggle visibility of multiple divs on button click?

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I want to toggle visibility of multiple divs using knockout. Below is the rough idea of my problem -

```
<button>Button 1</button>
<button>Button 2</button>
<button>Button 3</button>

<div> Div 1 </div>
<div> Div 2 </div>
<div> Div 3 </div>
```

By default, 'Div 1' should be visible.

When I click individual buttons it should display only the related divs based on the buttons clicked.

I have gone through the Knockout live examples but not getting how to do this efficiently.

Please help!

Comment: Are those buttons and corresponding divs rendered via a foreach loop over instances of a sub view model like "UserOptionVM", or are they just hardcoded?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The following will do a job for you.  It's not ideal, but should give you a platform to work on.

First, everything in Knockout is tied to a view model.  You want to be able to control the visibility of 3 divs, so here's a view model which might suit.  Like I said, not perfect :)

```
var buttonVm = new function(){
  var self = this;
  // Flags for visibility
  // Set first to true to cover your "first should be open" req
  self.button1Visible = ko.observable(true);
  self.button2Visible = ko.observable(false);
  self.button3Visible = ko.observable(false);

  self.toggle1 =  function(){
     self.button1Visible(!self.button1Visible());
  }

  self.toggle2 =  function(){
     self.button2Visible(!self.button2Visible());
  }

  self.toggle3 =  function(){
     self.button3Visible(!self.button3Visible());
  }

}
```

You'll need to change your markup to:-

```
<!-- events here.  When clicked call the referenced function -->
<button type="button" data-bind="click: toggle1">Button 1</button>
<button type="button" data-bind="click: toggle2">Button 2</button>
<button type="button" data-bind="click: toggle3">Button 3</button>

<!-- Visibility set here -->
<div data-bind="visible: button1Visible"> Div 1 </div>
<div data-bind="visible: button2Visible"> Div 2 </div>
<div data-bind="visible: button3Visible"> Div 3 </div>
```

Couple of things to note here.  First, I've added the **type** attribute.  Without it, the default behaviour of the button will be to try and submit your form.

Tying it all up:-

```
// Create view model
var vm = new buttonVm();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Comment: Thanks Paul,

That helped a bit. I was more concerned about disabling the other two divs when I click a button. We can say its like choosing a tab.
Can you help me with anything like that?

I want an efficient solution on this problem. How can it be done?